Print vs logging package while using AWS Airflow and EC2
While recently working on a PROD issue (and also earlier to that) of ETL project I am working on, I observed a peculiar behavior of python print() function.
Pipeline:
This was typical pipeline in which airflow DAG starts EC2 instance, SSH into EC2 using SSHHook/SSHOperator, copies python code from S3 to EC2, runs the code, deletes the code and then stops EC2 instance.
Issue:
AWS Airflow pipeline used to get stuck up after generating certain set of outputs without logging any error. Absolutely no indication of anything.
This issue was coming earlier in lower environment as well and there was no obvious problem in the code.
After trying really hard by the entire team and finally using brute force approach in solving this problem (I call it brute force approach of troubleshooting as I just remove everything from the code and start introducing small logical snippets 1 by 1 to check the failure point) and I found the culprit here as a single print() statement added earlier by someone for debug purpose. This was printing JSON file contents to EC2 console. When I commented it out, pipeline ran as expected till the end.
If I manually SSH into EC2 instance and execute the same python code through terminal with print() statement, I do not face this problem.
I tried doing some investigation around this and found very little.
At many places, its mentioned that use logger rather than print() but I am not able to link the reasons mentioned with my problem.
Just 1 difference between the two - is Python SSHHook usage vs manual SSH and manual execution of code.
Is there any additional setting required for SSHHook which manual SSH gets automatically?
Is there any limitation on console output size when done through SSHHook, as it work for some time and then gets stuck up?
